# EF Code First Many to Many with Lists of IDs

Tags: many-to-many, json.net, entity-framework-5

I have a Many-Many relationship between Users and Clients.  I'm using EF 5 Code First with Fluent API.  My entities look like this:

```
public class UserProfile 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Collection<Client> Clients { get; set; }
}

public class Client
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Collection<UserProfile> Users { get; set; }
}
```

In my UserProfile Configuration class have the following fluent API to declare the relationship:

```
HasMany(u => u.Clients)
    .WithMany(c => c.Users)
    .Map(m => m.MapLeftKey("UserId").MapRightKey("ClientId").ToTable("ClientUsers"));
```

All of this works perfectly, my Join table is created like you would expect.

My problem is that these entities are serialized to JSON and the circular dependency between them causes problems.  What I'm hoping to do is to serialize a list of the IDs of the Clients or Users.  Something like this:

```
public class UserProfile 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Collection<int> ClientIds { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual Collection<Client> Clients { get; set; }
}

public class Client
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Collection<int> UserIds { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual Collection<UserProfile> Users { get; set; }
}
```

How can I configure this using Fluent API?

Alternatively, I'd be equally happy if I could configure the JSON serializer to only serialize the IDs of the relationsips.  Something like this:

```
public class UserProfile 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [SomeAnnotation to make it only output the ID of each client]
    public virtual Collection<Client> Clients { get; set; }
}

public class Client
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [SomeAnnotation to make it only output the ID of each user]
    public virtual Collection<UserProfile> Users { get; set; }
}
```

In the end, I want my serialized JSON to look something like this:

```
List of all users:
[
  {"userId": 1, "clientIds": [1,2]},
  {"userId": 2, "clientIds": [2,3]}
]

List of all clients:
[
  {"clientId": 1, "userIds": [1]},
  {"clientId": 2, "userIds": [1,2]},
  {"clientId": 3, "userIds": [2]}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a workable solution that gave me what I want.  I'm curious to see if the community thinks this is a good pattern or not...

```
public class UserProfile 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual Collection<Client> Clients { get; set; }

    public ICollection<int> ClientIds
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Clients == null ? null : this.Clients.Select(c => c.Id).ToList();
        }
    }
}

public class Client
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual Collection<UserProfile> Users { get; set; }

    public ICollection<int> UserIds
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Users == null ? null : this.Users.Select(c => c.Id).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Then in my FluentAPI configuration

```
User Configuration:
Ignore(u => u.ClientIds);

Client Configuration:
Ignore(c => c.UserIds);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve this with fluent API - it is problem of your serialization, not the mapping. Your mapping is correct as-is. You must fix the serialization issue without changing the mapping - it may involve creating new DTO types projected from your mapped types which will be then correctly serialized.